# If for any $n \in \mathbb{N}: f^{(n)}(z_1)=f^{(n)}(z_2)$ then $f$ is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an holomorphic function

We know that exist two point $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that for any derivative order is $f^{(n)}(z_1)=f^{(n)}(z_2)$

Is it true that $f$ is a constant function?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to far ?

Comment: What about a linear transformation?

Comment: $g(z)=f(z)-f(z_2)$ is it a right way?

Comment: Consider the nonconstant holomorphic function $f(z) = \sin z$, and use points $z_1=0, z_2 = 2\pi$.

Comment: ok @GEdgar so... my question is false. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that the existence of distinct points as in the OP is possible iff the entire function $f$ is periodic and $z_2-z_1$ is a period. One way is obviously trivial since $f(z)=f(z+z_2-z_1)$ clearly implies the required relation by differentiating $n$ times and taking $z=z_1$

Conversely let $f(z)=\sum a_n (z-z_1)^n=\sum a_n (z-z_2)^n$ where the coefficients are the same by hypothesis. Then obviously:

$f(z+z_2-z_1)=\sum a_n ((z+z_2-z_1)-z_2)^n=\sum a_n (z-z_1)^n=f(z)$ for any $z \in \mathbb C$

Comment: my function is not periodic so is it true that f is constant?

Comment: yes if it is not periodic then it is constant (technically constant functions are periodic too of course, but...)

Comment: thanks for your valuable clarification

Comment: happy to be of help